# F1 key action in HP probook

Tags: laptop, hotkeys, function-keys, hp-laptop

Can someone please explain what this F1 hotkey does? On pressing fn+F1, I  get a blank (dark) screen for 1 second and then it goes back to normal (displays what was there before). It doesn't seem to be doing anything at all, at least in Ubuntu!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please explain what this F1 hotkey does?

It switches to Presentation mode.  I would assume the Presentation mode only supports Windows and/or you don't have another monitor connected to your device.

> Switch to another display mode when an external display is connected.

[HP PCs - Keyboard Shortcuts, Hotkeys, and Special Keys (Windows)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02951398#AbT4)

Answer (score 1):

That key is used to switch between connected displays to the PC. I think the symptom you explained of black screen is because you do not have any external display connected to your pc.
Reference: [Support HP](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c02951398) Check the section titled **Keys with icons or symbols**.
[image: Presentation mode]